# Fetch real-time audio input

Tags: performance, c, audio

The following code uses portAudio library to implement a real-time audio input through default input device. The SAMPLE format is float32 with 100 samples per frame.

The code is able to provide samples accurately but there is a significant lag that can be seen.

There are two questions which I would like to put forward.

1. Changing number of Sample per frame produce different number of Samples acquired. For e.g: When I run the program for 10 sec, it's giving around 811 frames (with 10 samples each) which is about 8110 samples and with 100 samples per frame, it gives 8 frames which is 800 samples for the same interval of time.

   I don't understand why such a difference for as of my understanding the sample acquisition for a particular amount of time should remain constant.
2. Can the code be optimized as I need to acquire 100 samples per Frame with a lesser lag (presently only 200 samples i.e 2 Frames per second) that I am getting now.

The code :

```
#include "portaudio.h"

#define FRAME_SIZE (100)    // Total samples that make a Frame. Change here if you wish to have different number of samples per frame
#define CB_SIZE (FRAME_SIZE * 64)   // Maximum limit of Frames handled by the Circular Buffer, here 64 as it would be kind of a delayed system.

typedef float SAMPLE;

PaStream *stream;
const int samplesPerFrame = FRAME_SIZE;

int sampleRate = 8000;
int numChannels = 1;

int num;
int fd;

PaSampleFormat sampleFormat;
PaError err = paNoError;

int i, j=0;

typedef struct{

    SAMPLE *sampleValues;
    int readFromCB;
    int writeToCB;
}
paTestData;                     // This structure will hold everything we need

void printFrame(paTestData *data){

    int readCount   = FRAME_SIZE;

    while(readCount > 0){

        printf("Data: %.8f\n", data->sampleValues[data->readFromCB++]); // Observing Sample Output
        readCount--;
    }

    if(data->readFromCB == CB_SIZE)
        data->readFromCB = 0;

    printf("\n\n");
}

static int paStreamRecordCallback( const void* input, void* output,
    unsigned long samplesPerFrame,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void* userData ) {

    paTestData *data = (paTestData*) userData;

        (void) output;          // Preventing unused variable warnings
        (void) timeInfo;
        (void) statusFlags;

    while(1){

        static int count = FRAME_SIZE;

        if(count > 0){
            const SAMPLE *writeValue = (const SAMPLE*)input; // Each Sample is casted here to float32
            memcpy(&data->sampleValues[data->writeToCB], writeValue, sizeof(SAMPLE)); // Each sample put to sampleValues

                    data->writeToCB++;
                    count--;
            if(data->writeToCB == CB_SIZE)
                data->writeToCB = 0;
        }

        if(count == 0){
            printFrame(data);
            count = FRAME_SIZE;
        }


        return paContinue;
    }

}        

int main(void);
int main(void){

    paTestData data;    // Object of paTestData structure

    fflush(stdout);

    data.writeToCB = 0;
    data.readFromCB = 0;

    data.sampleValues = (SAMPLE*)malloc(sizeof(SAMPLE)*CB_SIZE); // Memory allocation for Circular Buffer

    if(data.sampleValues == NULL){
        printf("Malloc failed to allocate ringBuffer\n");
        goto done;
    }

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if( err!= paNoError)
        goto done;

    PaStreamParameters inputParameter;

    inputParameter.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();
    if(inputParameter.device == paNoDevice){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: No input device found.\n");
        goto done;
    }

        /* Input Parameter structure definition here */
    inputParameter.channelCount = numChannels;
    inputParameter.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
    inputParameter.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(inputParameter.device)->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    inputParameter.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    err = Pa_OpenStream(

        &stream,
        &inputParameter,
        NULL,               // *outputParameter Not needed here
        sampleRate,
        samplesPerFrame,
        paClipOff,                      // All flags OFF
        paStreamRecordCallback,
        &data
    );

    if(err != paNoError)
        goto done;

    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if(err != paNoError)
        goto done;

    /* Recording audio here..Speak into the MIC */
    printf("\nRecording samples\n");
    fflush(stdout);



    while((err = Pa_IsStreamActive(stream)) == 1)
        Pa_Sleep(10);       // Time of input sample collection

    if(err < 0)
                goto done;

        err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    if(err != paNoError)
        goto done;

    printf("\nRecord program finished successfully!\n");

    /* Error handling here */
    done:

        Pa_Terminate();
        if( data.sampleValues )
            free( data.sampleValues );

        if( err != paNoError ){
            fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
            fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
            fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
            err = 1;
        }

        return err;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `readFrame` be `printFrame` (or vice versa)?

Comment: Oh sorry that's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, you *should not* call `printf` from a callback. It is unsafe (the callback executes in an async context), and in fact may be responsible for the lags and frame drops.

  On the other hand, you *should* test the flags to detect input errors.
- Copying a single sample with `memcpy` looks strange. A simple assignment would suffice. However, I'd rather `memcpy` an entire buffer.
- Never cast the `malloc` return value. It may mask a serious problem, if you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`. And, BTW, I don't see it included.
- There is a slight mismatch of terminology, which makes following the code harder. What you call `sample`, PortAudio calls `frame`, and what you call `frame`, PortAudio calls `buffer`. I recommend to stick with PortAudio terminology.

Edit:

The `statusFlags` passed to your callback contain, among other things, `paInputOverflow` and `paInputUnderflow` flags. If they are set, you have a problem (data lost, and data incorrect, respectively).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @vnp 
I got all your points except the first. Could you please elaborate on`you should test the flags to detect input errors` ?
And I have already included the header you suggested. I skipped them mentioning here.

Comment: @AshishK See edit.

Comment: I will surely try including the flags :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vpn for pointing out

> There is a slight mismatch of terminology, which makes following the
>   code harder. What you call sample, PortAudio calls frame, and what you
>   call frame, PortAudio calls buffer. I recommend to stick with
>   PortAudio terminology.

Here is my callback which is now giving me above 7000 samples per second (at 8000 sampling rate).

```
static int paStreamRecordCallback( const void* input, void* output,
    unsigned long framesToProcess,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void* userData ) {

    paTestData *data = (paTestData*) userData;
    const SAMPLE *readPtr = (const SAMPLE*)input;

    SAMPLE *writePtr = &data->frameValues[data->frameIndex];

    int i;

        (void) output;          // Preventing unused variable warnings
        (void) timeInfo;
        (void) statusFlags;

    unsigned long buffersRemaining = data->maxBufferIndex - data->bufferIndex;

    if(buffersRemaining > 0){

        for(i=0; i<framesToProcess; i++)
            *writePtr++ = *readPtr++;

        data->frameIndex += framesToProcess;
        data->bufferIndex++;
    }

    else if(buffersRemaining == 0){

        for(i=0; i<framesToProcess; i++)
            *writePtr++ = *readPtr++;

        data->frameIndex = 1;
        data->bufferIndex = 1;
    }
    return paContinue;

}
```

And I am printing the values in the main function by checking it through -

```
int main(){

    // Some Code

    while((err = Pa_IsStreamActive(stream)) == 1){

        Pa_Sleep(16);       // 16 ms so as to achieve 126 frames per buffer
        printValues(data.frameValues);
        printf("Frame Index: %d\nBuffer Index = %d\n", data.frameIndex, data.bufferIndex);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    // Other Code

}
```